# Rally web service API: get Hierarchical Requirements from a specific day in an Iteration

Tags: api, iteration, rally, user-stories

Is it possible to get the user stories (Hierarchical Requirements) from a specific day in an iteration using the Rally Web Service API? I'm developing a java application which will generate a history chart for an iteration. For example if the iteration was 14 days long, I need to get the Hierarchical Requirements with all their attributes for each day in that iteration, something like: [day1,Hierarchical Requirements], [day2,Hierarchical Requirements], and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the IterationCumulativeFlowData object in the WSAPI.
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

That should give you the total number of items and their todo/estimate totals for each day.